# Setting text color of cells in outline view while dragging

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview, textcolor

I have a split view window with an outline view on the left and a table view on the right. I want to be able to drag items from the table view and drop them onto items in the outline view. The dragging and dropping work fine, but the user feedback isn't quite visually what I want. Ideally, the behavior will be like the Finder, where folders become visually selected with white text as the dragged item passed over. In my implementation, however, the highlighting works as expected, but the text color remains black.

I'm change the highlighting in my draggingUpdated call, and attempt to change the text color in dataCellForTableColumn. I actually *can* change the color of the text to white in that method... but not when a drag operation is in place, though the method *is* fired while dragging.

The code:

```
- (NSDragOperation) draggingUpdated:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSPoint     windowLocation = [[self window] convertScreenToBase: [NSEvent mouseLocation]];
    NSPoint     viewLocation   = [self convertPoint: windowLocation fromView: nil];
    NSInteger   mouseRow       = [self rowAtPoint:viewLocation];

    // Get row at specified index
    if (highlightedRow != mouseRow) {
        NSTableCellView     *row;
       // If the highlighted row changed, revert it to a normal background color
        if (highlightedRow > -1) {
            row = [self viewAtColumn:0 row:highlightedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
            row.wantsLayer = YES;
            row.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor controlBackgroundColor] CGColor];
        }
        // Make sure the mouse if pointing to an existing row
        if (mouseRow < self.numberOfRows) {
            if ([[self itemAtRow:mouseRow] isKindOfClass:[ProjectTeamObject class]]) {
                row = [self viewAtColumn:0 row:mouseRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
                row.wantsLayer = YES;
                row.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor selectedContentBackgroundColor] CGColor];
                highlightedRow = mouseRow;
            }
        }
        else
            highlightedRow = -1;
    }
    return (NSDragOperationCopy);
}

- (NSCell *)outlineView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    NSCell          *dataCell = [tableColumn dataCell];
    NSTextFieldCell *cell     = [tableColumn dataCell];
    NSInteger       row       = [self rowForItem:item];
    
    cell = [tableColumn dataCell];
    if (dragging) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[ProjectTeamObject class]] && row <= self.numberOfRows)
            [cell setTextColor: [NSColor whiteColor]];
        else
            [cell setTextColor: [NSColor blackColor]];
    }
    return (dataCell);
```

highlightedRow and dragging are both globals and fairly straightforward.

Is there a problem with changing the text color of an outline view item while dragging, or is there perhaps a better way to do this I may be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the outline view view based or cell based?

Comment: It is cell based.

Comment: Does `[self viewAtColumn:0 row:highlightedRow makeIfNecessary:NO]` return a view? Is converting to a view based table view an option?

Comment: It does, yes; it returns an NSWrapperCellView which in turn includes an NSView. Setting the background color in draggingUpdated works as expected, but the setTextColor methods in dataCellForTableColumn don't have any effect while a drag is in progress. The text color remains black. My first choice is to get it working as is, but if I have to I'll move to a view based outline view. My fear, though, is that I may encounter the same behavior while dragging.

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement the default user feedback because it's not working or does the default user feedback work and are you trying to implement a custom user feedback?

Comment: I'm trying to reimplement the default feedback because I get no UI feedback at all when dragging items over the targets. All of the NSGragOperation methods (draggingEntered, draggingUpdated, etc) do get called, I just get no feedback. I imagine that may have something to do with how the UI elements are defined in the storyboard?

Comment: The item returned from `outlineView:child:ofItem:` must be unique, not `isEqual` to other items, and it must always be the same instance, not a copy or created every time. Otherwise `NSOutlineView` will get confused.

Comment: I believe this is the case, as each item in my outline view is a unique object.